# Is it possible to create a C# record with a private constructor?

Tags: c#, f#, record, discriminated-union

**Hello,**

I´m trying to rebuild a `discriminated union type` in C#.
I always created them with classes like this:

```cs
public abstract class Result
{
    private Result() { }

    public sealed class Ok : Result
    {
        public Ok(object result)    // don´t worry about object - it´s a sample
            => Result = result;
        
        public object Result { get; }
    }

    public sealed class Error : Result
    {
        public Error(string message)
            => Message = message;

        public string Message { get; }
    }
}
```

The problem is that is sooooo much boilerplate code when comparing to `F#`:

```fs
type Result =
    | Ok of result : object
    | Error of message : string
```

So I tried to rebuild the type with the help of C#9 `records`.

```cs
public abstract record Result
{
    public sealed record Ok(object result) : Result;
    public sealed record Error(string message) : Result;
}
```

Now it is way less code but now there is the problem that anyone can make new implementations of `Result` because the record has a public constructor.

Dose anyone have an idea how to restrict the implementations of the root record type?

Thanks for your help and your ideas!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I define additional initialization logic for the positional record?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64309291/how-do-i-define-additional-initialization-logic-for-the-positional-record)

Comment: Just add `private Result() { }` constructor yourself?

Comment: Just adding `private Result() { }` is not possible -> Error: `A constructor declared in a record with parameter list must have 'this' constructor initializer.`

Comment: The code provided in your question should not lead to such error while adding constructor, since this error means `Result` record has another constructor with parameters (like `abstract record Result(string something)`).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I solved it with the help of your comments and this other [stackoverflow article](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64749403/8848515).

```cs
namespace System.Runtime.CompilerServices
{
    internal static class IsExternalInit { }
}

namespace RZL.Core.Abstractions.DMS
{
    public abstract record Result
    {
        private Result() { }

        public sealed record Ok(object result) : Result;
        public sealed record Error(string message) : Result;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

While you can definitely add a private constructor to a record, doing so is probably not what you want. As it **does not** guarantee that no other type outside your record can inherit it. That's because records always have a generated, protected copy constructor. Your `Result` can be simply inherited while having a private constructor:

```cs
public abstract record Result
{
    private Result() { }

    public sealed record Ok(object result) : Result;
    public sealed record Error(string message) : Result;
}

public record UnexpectedResult : Result
{
    public UnexpectedResult() : base(new Result.Error("dummy"))
    {
    }
}

// ...

Result result = new UnexpectedResult();
```

So you can never truly guarantee that an object of type `Result` will always be either `Result.Ok` or `Result.Error` (at least at compile time). You have three options:

1. Prevent external inheritance at runtime by directly implementing a copy constructor:

   ```cs
   public abstract record Result
   {
       // ...

       protected Result(Result _)
       {
           if (this is not Ok && this is not Error)
           {
               throw new InvalidOperationException("External inheritance is not allowed");
           }
       }
   }
   ```
2. Accept the fact that your type hierarchy will never be *closed*,
3. Use classes.

Answer (score -1):

If you don't want to abstract the record you don't have to:

```cs
public record ClientVerificationResponse
{
    protected ClientVerificationResponse(bool succeeded)
    {
        Succeeded = succeeded;
    }

    [MemberNotNullWhen(true, nameof(Credentials))]
    public bool Succeeded { get; init; }

    public ClaimsPrincipal? Credentials { get; init; }

    public static ClientVerificationResponse Success(ClaimsPrincipal claimsPrincipal) => new(true) { Credentials= claimsPrincipal };
    public static ClientVerificationResponse Fail => new(false);
}
```