# Enforcing Instance Creation of Record Types Through Specific Methods in C#

Tags: c#, record, primary-constructor

I've implemented the `Result` pattern for error handling in C# using record types, as shown in the code snippet below:

```
namespace WebApi.Utils
{
    public struct Roid { }

    public record Result<TResult, TError>
    {
        public static Success<TResult> Success(TResult result) => new Success<TResult>(result);
        public static Failure<TError> Failed(TError error) => new Failure<TError>(error);
    }

    public record Success<TResult>(TResult Value) : Result<TResult, Roid>;
    public record Failure<TError>(TError Error) : Result<Roid, TError>;
}
```

In this setup, `Success` and `Failure` are record types that inherit from a generic `Result` record type. My goal is to ensure that instances of `Success<TResult>` and `Failure<TError>` can only be created through the `Success` and `Failure` static methods defined in the `Result` record, respectively.

How can I enforce this constraint, ensuring that `Success` and `Failure` instances are only created via these specific methods, and not through any other means?

Comment: Is https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69283960/is-it-possible-to-create-a-c-sharp-record-with-a-private-constructor an option?

Answer (score 1):

You can't enforce this while still using the record with [positional syntax for property definition](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/record#positional-syntax-for-property-definition)/[primary constructor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/instance-constructors#primary-constructors), so the only option is to migrate to "explicit" property definitions combined with explicit default ctor:

```cs
public record Success<TResult> : Result<TResult, Roid>
{
    internal Success(){}
    public required TResult Value { get; init; } 
}
```

With corresponding changes to the method:

```cs
public static Success<TResult> Success(TResult result) => new() { Value = result };
```

Note that this will still allow creation of new instances via `with` (see the [nondestructive mutation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/record#nondestructive-mutation) section of the docs):

```cs
Success<int> s = ...;
var newS = s with { Value = 2 };
```

You can prevent this in runtime by introducing copy ctor which will throw:

```
public record Success<TResult> : Result<TResult, Roid>
{
   // ...
   protected Success(Success<TResult> _) : base(_) => throw new NotImplementedException();
}
```

But for compile time you will need to write a custom Roslyn analyzer (or just switch to using "ordinary" classes).

P.S.

I would argue that moving the static methods to static non-generic class would be beneficial in terms ease of usage :

```cs
public static class Result
{
    public static Success<TResult> Success<TResult>(TResult result) => new(){ Value = result };
    public static Failure<TError> Failed<TError>(TError error) => new(){Error = error};
}
```